# Making Knockout validations not fire on page load

Tags: validation, knockout.js

I am trying to implement validations using Knockout and have tried the "Bob" example from [here](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/extenders.html)

```
<p data-bind="css: { error: firstName.hasError }">
    <input data-bind='value: firstName, valueUpdate: "afterkeydown"' />
    <span data-bind='visible: firstName.hasError, text: firstName.validationMessage'> </span>
</p>
<p data-bind="css: { error: lastName.hasError }">
    <input data-bind='value: lastName, valueUpdate: "afterkeydown"' />
    <span data-bind='visible: lastName.hasError, text: lastName.validationMessage'> </span>
</p>
```

Source code: View model

```
ko.extenders.required = function(target, overrideMessage) {
    //add some sub-observables to our observable
    target.hasError = ko.observable();
    target.validationMessage = ko.observable();

    //define a function to do validation
    function validate(newValue) {
       target.hasError(newValue ? false : true);
       target.validationMessage(newValue ? "" : overrideMessage || "This field is required");
    }

    //initial validation
    validate(target());

    //validate whenever the value changes
    target.subscribe(validate);

    //return the original observable
    return target;
};

function AppViewModel(first, last) {
    this.firstName = ko.observable(first).extend({ required: "Please enter a first name" });
    this.lastName = ko.observable(last).extend({ required: "" });
}

ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel("Bob","Smith"));
```

CSS:

```
.validationError{
        border:solid 1px red;
    }
```

On initial page load there wont be any data in the text boxes. So I removed the hardcoded names.
Now the validation message is showing on page load instead of when the user leaves the text boxes.
Somehow KO is thinking during the page load that the textbox value has changed and firing the validation code.

How do I stop this from happening?

Here is the use case I am trying to attempt.
I have two text boxes, one needs to show a red border with no message and the other needs to show a message on validation.

[Sample here](http://jsfiddle.net/15n0t7qh/)

Thanks.

Comment: if you are using the `ko.extenders.required` from the linked page just remove the line `//initial validation validate(target());` line to disable the initial validation

Comment: @nemesv this removes the initial validation, but now the validation does not fire even when the user leaves the textbox.

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle for it?

Comment: Please don't ask for / add a fiddle without also adding the code to the question, otherwise the question depends on an offsite link (which may rot).

Comment: You need to use also the `notify: 'always'` extender because otherwise when the blur event fires knockout won't fire the change event for the observable because there is no chagne so your validator won't fire `http://jsfiddle.net/460sLwyr/

Answer (score 0):

The initial validation is triggered by the line:

```
 validate(target());
```

Comment it out.

But now, if you enter the empty textbox, and jump out of it, there is no change: the field was empty when focused, and was empty when blured. So the observable doesn't change, and the subscription isn't triggered.

So, what you'd need to do is to trigger the validation also on blur, and not only on change. You'd need to subscribe the validation to the blur event of the bound element to make the additional validation. But that's not possible because you cannot accces the element(s) to which the observable is (are) bound.

And as far as I can think of a solution, as you only have access to the observable, you cannot achieve what you want with an extender.

You'd need to create a [custom binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html) instead, that allows you to acces the element. In this case you have acces to the element, the value accessor (equivalent to the `target()` of an extender), and all the other bindings in the element. This is the signature of a custom binding update function:

```
function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings)
```

I've created a sample implementation of a `required` custom binding handler that you can use as an satrting point. [Here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jbustos/ktczzmd9/), and here is the code:

HTML:

```
<input type="text" data-bind="value: name, required: 'Name required'">
<span data-bind="visible: name.hasError, text: name.requiredMessage"></span>
<br/>
<input type="text" data-bind="value: age, required: 'Age required'">
<span data-bind="visible: age.hasError, text: age.requiredMessage"></span>
```

JavaScript:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.required = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        // This will be called when the binding is first applied to an element
        // Set up any initial state, event handlers, etc. here
        console.log('Init', element);
        var valueObs = allBindings.get('value');
        valueObs.hasError = ko.observable(false);
        valueObs.requiredMessage = ko.observable(ko.unwrap(valueAccessor()));
        valueObs.firstTime = true;
        $(element).blur(function() {
            console.log('Blur');
            valueObs.hasError(!valueObs());
        });
    },

    update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        // This will be called once when the binding is first applied to an element,
        // and again whenever any observables/computeds that are accessed change
        // Update the DOM element based on the supplied values here.
        var valueObs = allBindings.get('value');
        console.log('value: ', valueObs());
        if (valueObs.firstTime) {
            valueObs.firstTime = false;
            return;
        }
        valueObs.hasError(!valueObs());
    }
};

var vm = {
    name: ko.observable(""),
    age: ko.observable("")
};

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

Comment: Did like this <input data-bind='value: firstName, valueUpdate: "blur"' />, still no go!

Comment: @Codehelp. I'm sorry this answer was not exact. Now I've added extra information for you.

Comment: @Codehelp added alternative to original answer